# Error while building Flutter APK for android-arm only

Tags: flutter, gradle

I got into this problem since last month. I can build APK for android-arm64, android-x86, all of them combined but not specifically for android-arm.

I use this command to build:-

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm --analyze-size
```

After running this I'm getting the error:-

```
 Building with sound null safety 

Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -2147483645


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.      

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 54s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          295.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Output for `flutter doctor` is:-

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.527], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.65.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

- I tried changing gradle versions to **6.7-all**, **7.3.1-bin** and **7.2-bin**
- I tried removing flutter folder and reinstalling it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with flutter itself after the new update.
It is covered in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97764)